# Unity не работает коллиззия

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Только начал изучать Unity2D и решил написать игру, проблема в том, что коллизия что-то не работает(

Вот скрины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинку игроку я просто еще не рисовал, сделал из той же картинки)

Так почему же не работает коллизия??

P.S. "Игрок" проваливается в бездну, и все)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что ваш объект ("игрок") не "твердый". Добавьте персонажу колайдер.